# bash error while installing from command line

Tags: command-line, bash

When I am trying to use command prompt commands, I cannot get it installed

```
 nget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-15-current.tar.gz
```

error

```
-bash:  nget: no command found
```

command

```
yum install rpm
```

error

```
-bash: yum: no command found
```

command

```
pip install asterisk
```

error

```
-bash: install: no command found
```

I tried

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

upgrade worked, and installing asterisk also done without error. How to resolve these errors of first two commands (nget and yum)? any upgrades needed to be done ?

Comment: please do `which nget` and for `yum` are you using Ubuntu or CentOS?

Comment: ubuntu, Sorry i didnt mention OS, though its ubuntu forum alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is in the default repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Asterisk the right way open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install asterisk
```

See how easy it is to install Asterisk the right way, and Asterisk which is installed by apt will be updated automatically when updates become available like any other software from the default Ubuntu repositories.

---

There's no point in installing an Asterisk .rpm file in Ubuntu, but installing Asterisk the wrong way anyway would require changing a few things.

1. Instead of nget use wget.

   ```
   wget -c http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-15-current.tar.gz
   ```
2. Install yum with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install yum
   ```
3. Install pip with the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip # for Python 3.x  
   sudo apt install python-pip  # for Python 2.x
   ```